# Outlook 2016 Win 10 Enterprise

Tags: microsoft-outlook, templates, auto-reply

When I receive emails with a specific subject, I want to reply with a template

- However, the template doesn't copy the original body of the email and I must have to link it properly elsewhere: 
   I tried creating a code that will do that,  but *"Run Script"* is no longer an option in business rules.

  ```batch
  Sub AutoReply(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
      Dim olkReply As Outlook.MailItem
      Set olkReply = Item.Reply
      With olkReply
          .Subject = "Your Subject Goes Here"
          .HTMLBody = "This is an extensive but privatized body content replacement.<bt><br>" & Item.HTMLBody
          .Send
      End With
      Set olkReply = Nothing
  End Sub
  ```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this automatically?

Comment: According to my test, if you set rule to reply a message with specific subject using a template, the template will not copy the original body of the email, this is by design. You may try achiving this with VBA code.